# Global refresh Angular 2+ app without page refresh

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe, angular-changedetection

I was wondering if it was possible to perform a global refresh on my Angular (2+) app. I am using the OnPush change detection strategy for performance.

I have created a service that translates words from my templates to the browser language of the user. These pipes are pure (for performance reasons and the language should not be updated frequently).

What I am trying to achieve is that I can change my language dynamically. So basically I want to change all pure pipes when the user selects a different language.

I have solved this by doing a page refresh (`window.location.reload()`), but now I was wondering if it was possible by doing a complete change detection cycle. I have tried using the ApplicationRef and ChangeDetectionRef but these pure pipes won't get updated. Is this even possible?

Comment: this guy is doing what you want and i use it, maybe the source code helps https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: Thanks! I've checked out the ngx-translate repository. From what I can tell his translate-pipe is using the pure: false metadata. I wanted to know if its possible with pure pipes.